Microsoft identity provider disabled in azure function app
Im trying to add an identity provider to my azure function app but the item "Microsoft" is disabled in my options. I need this to be able to call my function in ADF via System-assigned managed identity.
Anyone has any idea how to enable it?


What is the version of your app?

@Harshitha The runtime version is 4.1036.3.3

What is your plan and can give all the function app details

It will be enabled for everyone if the admin has enabled it for the subscription

To add identity provider :
Open External identities and then click on All identity providers and configure Microsoft in it.

Or you can set up identity providers using:

